Python techniques for determining if a ball is above or in the goal using camera footage
Problem Description:
I am currently working on a project where I need to determine whether a soccer ball is above or in the goal using camera footage. I have already developed a working model to detect the ball and another method to determine if it has crossed the goal line. However, I'm struggling to find an effective technique to distinguish whether the ball is above the goal or actually inside it.
Current Attempts:
I have experimented with various depth estimation techniques, including MiDaS, ZoeDepth, and other models from huggingface, but have found them to be inconsistent and unreliable for accurately determining the ball's position relative to the goal.
Images:
The footage i'm working with looks like this:
Goal 1
Goal 2
Question:
I would appreciate any suggestions or techniques in Python that could help me address this problem. Specifically, how can I determine if the ball is above the goal or inside it based on camera footage? Are there any relevant libraries or computer vision techniques that could assist with this task?

if not code -> ball not found.  Read this please https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

You could modify your input images to simulate a top-down view, which would probably make the image easier for the model to interpret, or even remove the need for a vision model entirely

if the ball is inside it will be partially occluded by the net, Otherwise it won't.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

First thought would be to move the camera to a different angle (side-view) to get a better frame to work with. Supposing this is a camera from one of your local football teams, this is probably not possible. If you'd do this, you would also need two, so we're in a bit of a pickle here.
You could easily detect if it's inside the goal, by detecting net movement. This is however not your question: You need to know if the ball goes above or below the goal.
I'd try out Structure from Motion (SfM), though it usually works better with multiple angles & imagery. Maybe you could use LiDAR data, most modern phones have LiDAR sensors in their cameras, you could try to create your own 3D Model with images of the goal for your project. If you'd do this, you'd want to test it out at home first to see if it's worth pursuing.
Also, it'd be helpful to know the project's purpose. If it's for actual games (not training), maybe you could use the microphone of the camera to tell if it's a goal. Do you have any other cameras besides these two? Or do you have any other tech / ... on the field that could help?
